# Logger basicConfig - can't set a specific file folder

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to set the log file to a specific folder.
The path is `project-folder/logs/test_num/test_number.log`
for exmaple:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s  %(name)s :%(levelname)s :%(message)s", filename=project-folder/logs/123/123.logs, filemode="a", force=True)
```

When trying to set to this path, log file isn't created, and if there are other files under this path they been deleted.
When I'm trying to set to `project-folder/logs` it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add quotation marks.

Comment: `filename="project-folder/logs/123/123.logs"`

Comment: there is quotation marks..
and the issue is only with log file under the specific path. with text file works fine, and with the path "project-folder/logs/123.log" also works fine

Comment: You also need to ensure that the directory for the log file exists and is writable by the program doing the logging. Is that the case?

Comment: I already have the path "project-folder/logs/123", the logger shouldn't create the log inside this path?